# What format is opencv's canny output image (c++)?

Tags: c++, opencv

I need to use the Canny edge detector and I am using opencv's one (after blurring it, of course). I need to do further image processing on the canny output and I have seen that the canny output is colored (I was expecting it to be a black and white binary image.) I am wishing to group similar edges of a graph together and I believe that the color data of the canny output can be very valuable to me. However, I do not know what the color data represents.

Does anyone know what the color data is?

It seems that the continuous edges of the canny output are of the same color, but are they exactly of the same color? If not, how could I group them (the color must surely come into play here)?

Here is one of my Canny outputs if you wish to see what I am talking about:[image]

Here is my code if it's any help (it's just canny processing) :

```
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

using namespace cv;

/// Global variables

Mat src, src_gray;
Mat dst, detected_edges;

int edgeThresh = 1;
int lowThreshold;
int const max_lowThreshold = 100;
int ratio = 3;
int kernel_size = 3;
char* window_name = "Edge Map";

/**
 * @function CannyThreshold
 * @brief Trackbar callback - Canny thresholds input with a ratio 1:3
 */
void CannyThreshold(int, void*)
{
  /// Reduce noise with a kernel 3x3
  blur( src_gray, detected_edges, Size(3,3) );

  /// Canny detector
  Canny( detected_edges, detected_edges, lowThreshold, lowThreshold*ratio, kernel_size );

  /// Using Canny's output as a mask, we display our result
  dst = Scalar::all(0);

  src.copyTo( dst, detected_edges);
  imshow( window_name, dst );
 }


/** @function main */
int main( int argc, char** argv )
{
  /// Load an image
  src = imread( argv[1] );

  if( !src.data )
  { return -1; }

  /// Create a matrix of the same type and size as src (for dst)
  dst.create( src.size(), src.type() );

  /// Convert the image to grayscale
    cvtColor( src, src_gray, COLOR_BGR2GRAY );

  /// Create a window
    namedWindow( window_name, WINDOW_AUTOSIZE );

  /// Create a Trackbar for user to enter threshold
  createTrackbar( "Min Threshold:", window_name, &lowThreshold, max_lowThreshold, CannyThreshold );

  /// Show the image
  CannyThreshold(0, 0);

  /// Wait until user exit program by pressing a key
  waitKey(0);

  return 0;
  }
```

Comment: Sorry, really stupid question here. I just realised the color of the pixels were the same as the original images. However, if anyone has an idea on how to group continuous features, such as the line, answers are welcome.

Comment: Maybe you'd care to share the input image too?